# MVC view throwing 500.19 error when using the direct url, but not when routed via the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have two views in my mvc application.  They are both stored within area, A, and within folder, home.

I recently was changing the properties of my project and it asked to reconfigure my site configs in iis as always I clicked yes.  Since then I have been getting a 500.19 error saying that my configuration file has incorrect data.

At this point I was thoroughly confused.  I compared my web.configs against other application web.configs and there really was no difference.  So, I then changed my routing so that inputting this. :

```
http://stackoverflow/myarea/home
```

Actually returns my view of. :

```
http://stackoverflow/myarea/home/index
```

So, when I just input. :

`http://stackoverflow/myarea/home/index`  => this errors with 500.19

but when I use. :

`http://stackoverflow/myarea/home` => this works with no error but brings up the same view as the above would

I have tried a lot of things blowing away my application in iis and recreating it, numerous iis resets, deleting my view and recreating it.  Nothing has came close to working.

Now what is really odd is I have another view in the same folder. :

```
http://stackoverflow/myarea/home/myotherview
```

When I go directly to this url above it works perfectly no issues, no 500.19.

So, it is as if something is tying my one view to this issue.  I know that this is an odd one, but I am lost on what to try next.  Hoping someone has seen something like this before.  I know a 500.19 is usually an issue within the web.config, but after the other page works I think it is some sort of setting I am just unaware of.

Comment: What does the route(s) look like?

Answer (score 0):

500.19 is a configuration issue.

See here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx

I suspect that you do not have the routes in the global.asax or in the areas registration asax file setup properly.  Without seeing your routes I cannot help you more specifically.  But you might need to setup something like this in

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultIndexRoute",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
}
```

in the AreaRegistrations.asax file it will be

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "DefaulAreatIndexRoute",
        "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional},
        new [] {"My.Area.Namespace.Controllers"} // optional namespace in case there is a conflict
    );
}
```

this is a catch-all kind of route.  MVC will choose your route based on the first one that matches.  So you will want this at the bottom of the list most likely.  With more specific routes specified above it.

Basically if mvc cannot find an adequate route it will throw it back to IIS to figure out in which you will most likely get an error.

Please post your route configs so we can help you a bit more.  Thanks.